# Generating a grid in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I am trying to draw a grid with OpenGL 3+. However, I have a problem generating it. My code is:

```
vec3 *verts = new vec3[(resolution)*(resolution)];
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<resolution;i++)
    for(int j = 0;j<resolution;j++)
    {
        verts[count++] = vec3(i,0,j);
    }

GLuint *indices = new GLuint[(resolution-1)*(resolution-1)*6];

count = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<resolution-1;i++)
{
   for(int j = 0;j<resolution-1;j++)
    {
        indices[count++] = i*resolution+j;
        indices[count++] = i*resolution+j+1;
        indices[count++] = (i+1)*resolution+j;
        indices[count++] = (i+1)*resolution+j;
        indices[count++] = i*resolution+j+1;
        indices[count++] = (i+1)*resolution+j+1;
    }
}
```

I draw the geometry as GL_TRIANGLES and do not see anything.

Comment: Why would you draw a grid as triangles? Use GL_LINES

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah, the grid should be filled. Actually, I will displace the vertex height in vertex shader to draw a terrain. By the way, GL_LINES do not work anyway.

Comment: @RostakaGmfun: and GL_POINTS? if not, post your drawing routine and shaders if present.

Comment: @RostakaGmfun: And what is the issue you are having with this code? It should work in principle. So the mistake might be in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the problem - the GL buffers sizes were set to incorrect values, and so not rendered, although grid generation routine works well.